# iOS NSMutableString split like java's String method split()

Tags: iphone, ios

I hava a NSString which uses $ as delimiters, e.g.

```
    NSMutableString *str = @"AA$BB$CC";
```

So, my questio is: is there a method to split that NSMutableString by delimiters '$' and store into an array,
just like in java:

```
    String[] list = str.split()
```

thanks advancde.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
NSArray* splittedArray= [str componentsSeparatedByString:@"$"];
for (NSString *component in splittedArray) {
  NSLog(@"%@", component);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. you can use `componentsSeparatedByString` method which works similar to `split()` method.   Example:`NSArray* list= [str componentsSeparatedByString:@"$"];`